# How does the 3-attack sequence work with multiple skills?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

The Monk’s primary skills follow a certain sequence of hits, in which every third hit behaves differently. How does the “hit-tracking” for these skills work with multiple skills?

Specifically, if I attack with primary skill A, then primary skill B (with elective mode), and then A again, will the final attack be considered a 3rd hit for the purpose of these skills?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. As long as you're chaining these "combo" moves together without interrupting using a non-combo move, the hits will continue to count up even if you switch which specific skill you're using.

A really good choice appears to be to use Way of the Hundred Fists as your second strike, since the second strike of that one hits multiple times but the other ones do not.